# Is there a way to compare the elements of two lists residing in a json?

Tags: python, list, python-re

I'm currently working on parsing the messages from logs and printing them out. Please see the program below before I explain my problem.

```py
    count = 0
    error_list = ["*SSH connection as gentan (using password) successful.*", "*Deployment State Updated to ATTEMPTING_CONNECTION*"]
    
    for i in data['deploymentStatus']['page']:
        count = count + 1
        regex = re.compile(error_list)
        if re.findall(regex, i['history']) is True:
            string = """
        ========================
            TARGET # %s
        ========================
        [+] IP      => %s
        [+] HISTORY => %s""" % (count, i['address'], i['history'])
            print(string)
```

Here's the code what **i['history']** is equals to.

```py
i['history] = ["13/04/2021 05:42:59:589Z: Attempting connection via ssh as gentan.", "13/04/2021 05:42:59:589Z: Deployment State Updated to ATTEMPTING_CONNECTION"]
```

Now lastly what I want is, I want the if statement to only pring the logs that match with each other in the **error_list** and **i['history']**

The reason why its not matching in my case is because it starts with date and time, is there a way in python to parse that out and compare the string only?

I would greatly appreciate any help. I can also post the complete **data['deploymentStatus']['page']** json file but its too long to post here **12k+ lines**.

Comment: "Is there any way" is a non-issue for Stack Overflow. Since you're on a general-purpose computer that is barely short of a Turing machine, the answer is almost always "yes". The follow-up question, "How do I do it?", is too broad for Stack Overflow.  
Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You've already identified the points you need: string processing to identify and remove the parts you don't want, then compare with some other reference strings.  Repeat the associated tutorials, write the code, and (if you have trouble), supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).

Comment: The argument to `re.compile()` has to be a single string, not a list.

Comment: `re.findall(regex, i['history'])` returns a list of matches, so `is True` will never succeed.

Comment: `*` at the beginning of a regexp is invalid. It has to be preceded by a pattern, it matches any sequence of that pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions. Just use the `in` operator to test if one of the strings in `error_list` is in the history string.

```
error_list = ["SSH connection as gentan (using password) successful", "Deployment State Updated to ATTEMPTING_CONNECTION"]

for i in data['deploymentStatus']['page']:
    if any(error in i['history'] for error in error_list):
        print("""
        ========================
            TARGET # %s
        ========================
        [+] IP      => %s
        [+] HISTORY => %s""" % (count, i['address'], i['history']))

count = len(data['deploymentStatus']['page']) # no need to calculate this in the loop
```